# Firefox renders table within a div way off to the right, but looks normal in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to learn HTML / CSS better.  I'm developing a website for a friend's catering company, and I did all my development looking at Chrome and IE, and got everything looking the way I wanted.  But then after all that work, I went and looked in Firefox and everything is rendered differently, with content way out of place. I've tried making various CSS changes, but can't figure it out.

I've got the following web page...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
  <title>Spot On Dining &amp; Consulting</title>  
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>  
  <!-- Main Container -->
  <div id="container">
    <!-- Banner -->
    <div id="banner" class="bannerAndMenuStyle">
      <img src="images/Banner.png" width="940" height="200" />
    </div>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div id="menu" class="bannerAndMenuStyle">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/home.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/home2.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='images/home.jpg';" /></a>
      <a href="about.html"><img src="images/about.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/about2.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='images/about.jpg';" /></a>
      <a href="food.html"><img src="images/food.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/food2.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='images/food.jpg';" /></a>
      <a href="services.html"><img src="images/services.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/services2.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='images/services.jpg';" /></a>
      <a href="contact.html"><img src="images/contact.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/contact2.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='images/contact.jpg';" /></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="contentWrapper">
      <table id="foodContentTextWrapper" cellspacing="15px">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="12" valign="bottom">
            <h1 align="center">Food</h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="420px" valign="top">
          <td colspan="3" valign="top" align="center">
            <table>
              <tr height="5px"><td></td></tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                  <img src="images/CheesePlatter1.jpg"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr height="25px"><td></td></tr>              
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                  <img src="images/HogRoast.jpg"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr height="25px"><td></td></tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                  <img src="images/Buffet5.jpg"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr height="25px"><td></td></tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                  <img src="images/SoupAndSandwich.jpg"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr height="20px"><td></td></tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td colspan="6" valign="top">
            <h2>          
              <p>At Spot On Dining, we firmly believe that variety is the spice of life.  We love to create healthy, delicious food from any cuisine that the event calls for.</p>
              <p>We will work with you to develop a personalized menu that fits your needs.  We have experience with anything from pig roasts to vegetarian feasts, with a large variety of vegetarian and vegan dishes.</p>
              <p>Below are just a few styles of dishes that our customers commonly enjoy ordering...</p>
              <ul style="list-style-image: url(images/Silverware.png);height:280px;line-height:20px;vertical-align:middle;">
                <li>Southwest Appetizers and Entrees</li>
                <li>Mediterranean Pasta and Salads</li>
                <li>Traditional Italian Entrees</li>
                <li>Whole Roasted Pig (traditional Lechon)</li>
                <li>Cheese and Vegetable Platters</li>
                <li>Lasagnas (meat or vegetarian)</li>
                <li>Braised and Pulled Wild Boar Leg</li>
                <li>Soups, Salads and Sandwiches of all sorts</li>
                <li>BBQ Skewers (Chicken, Shrimp, Beef, Pork)</li>
                <li>Filipino Dishes (Lengua, Menudo, etc.)</li>
                <li>French Desserts (Creme Brulee, Crepes, etc.)</li>                
              </ul>            
              <p>Have a hankering for a favorite childhood dish from back home, but just can't find it anywhere?  No problem!  Just give us a description and we will be glad to suit your needs.</p>
              <p>Special dietary needs? No problem!  We are very experienced with making dishes appropriate for Diebetic, Low Sodium, and other special needs, without sacrificing taste.</p>
            </h2>
          </td>
          <td colspan="3" valign="top">
            <table>
              <tr height="5px"><td></td></tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                  <img src="images/Skewers.jpg"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                  <img src="images/App2.jpg"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="center">
                  <img src="images/StuffedJaps.jpg"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr height="20px"><td></td></tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, in Firefox the top banner and the top menu look exactly the same as in IE and Chrome.  But then all the content of the table is rendered off to the right, instead of being underneath the menu, like it does correctly in IE and Chrome.

This is my main.css file.

```
body {background-color: #777777;background-repeat: no-repeat;}
a:link {color: #CCCCCC;}
a:visited {color: #CCCCCC;}

#container {width:941px;min-height:600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
.bannerAndMenuStyle img{display:block;float:left;border:0;}
#homeContentTopImage {padding-top:25px;}
#contentWrapper {height:auto; min-height:744px;background:linear-gradient(#D9E8D9, #888888);color:black;font-family:Verdana;}
#homeContentTextWrapper {padding-left:25px;padding-bottom:25px;font-family:Verdana;font-size:0.6em}
#homeContentTextWrapper h2{font-style:italic}
#homeContentTextWrapper p{font-style:normal}
#aboutContentTextWrapper {display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;padding-top:25px;padding-left:25px;padding-bottom:25px;font-family:Verdana;font-size:0.6em}
#servicesContentTextWrapper {font-family:Verdana;}
#servicesContentTextWrapper h2 {font-size:0.9em;}
#foodContentTextWrapper {font-family:Verdana;}
#foodContentTextWrapper h2 {font-size:0.9em;}
```

Any ideas why this happens in Firefox, while it looks normal in Chrome and IE?  I'm sure it's something about the CSS, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear:both` to `#contentWrapper`. I think the floated `img` in the banner is causing problems because nothing is cleared afterwords.